# PHP: how to open a zip

Tags: php, zip

is there an easy way to open and create a zip with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [PHP Zip library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php).
Here are a few tutorials on the subject:

- [Devzone.zend.com](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2105)
- [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/how-to-open-zip-files-with-php/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like the [zip](https://www.php.net/zip) library ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the documentation for [`ZipArchive`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php), particularly the [`open`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php) method.

You use it like this:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'newname.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```